# How to make a connection between Android and Arduino mega2560

Tags: android, arduino, server

I have an Arduino mega2560 which has a WiFi connection. I want to add a button to the Arduino so whenever someone clicks on it (physically), it sends a notification to my Android app (which I am building now).

I have tried to look for a way to do it and I understand now that I need to build a server. I have zero knowledge with servers. How can I start with this? am I in the right way? do I really need a server? where can I start?

Comment: This can help you to understand how to implement a basic server on an arduino http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Webserver-with-Arduino-Mega-2560/

Comment: I have used this one:
https://petestechprojects.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/mini-server-on-arduino-esp8266/
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are probably using a serial module you can just use the arduino wifi library. Here is how to make a wifi webserver https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebServer ... for the button you just have to use a typical digitalread of the input pin.

Comment: I am using esp8266.. its not WiFi shield can I stell use this library?
and for the button, I have found this link:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Button
thank you.

Comment: Yes you can use the module with wifi library.If you just wanna connect to a open network of a phone,please refer to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ConnectNoEncryption